# Spring boot application conflicting bean instances between test and non test code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an interface and its implementation in the non test code as follows

```
public interface ClientQueryServiceInterface {
    public String getName();
}

@Service
public class ClientQueryServiceImpl1 implements ClientQueryServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "this is ClientQueryServiceImpl1";
    }
}
```

The above 2 are in different files.

Under `source/test/java`, when I try to create another instance of the above interface, it complains that there are 2 instances found. I know it is trying to create an instance from test and non test as well. But I read online that I can create my separate bean instance in test by either using static class or doing an import of the class that has the config.
Here is my test file code

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyConfigClass {
        @Bean
        public ClientQueryServiceInterface getInst1() {
            return new ClientQueryServiceInterface(){
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "this is from test instance creation and is of type 1";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    ClientQueryServiceInterface clif;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        String s = clif.getName();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

The error has the excerpt as
`expected single matching bean but found 2: clientQueryServiceImpl1,getInst1`

Another follow up I have is that once I can get past the above issue, I want to write 2 different test cases and want to create 2 different Bean implementations only for testing and use one instance for one test case and another for another test case.
I know a bit about the @Qualifier annotation but I do not want to modify the non test code and do not want to add any @Qualifier in the non test code.
How do I solve the 2 issues